# Count character occurrences in a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, pattern-matching

How can I count the number of `"_"` in a string like `"bla_bla_blabla_bla"`?

Answer (score 568):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

std::string s = "a_b_c";
std::string::difference_type n = std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), '_');

// alternatively, in C++20
auto count = std::ranges::count(s, '_');
```

See [`std::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) and [`std::ranges::count`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/count).

Answer (score 40):

Pseudocode:

```
count = 0
For each character c in string s
  Check if c equals '_'
    If yes, increase count
```

EDIT: C++ example code:

```
int count_underscores(string s) {
  int count = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    if (s[i] == '_') count++;

  return count;
}
```

Note that this is code to use together with `std::string`, if you're using `char*`, replace `s.size()` with `strlen(s)` - but assign that to a variable outside the `for` loop to avoid scanning the whole string on every loop iteration.

Also note: I can understand you want something "as small as possible", but I'd suggest you to use this solution instead. As you see you can use a function to encapsulate the code for you so you won't have to write out the `for` loop everytime, but can just use `count_underscores("my_string_")` in the rest of your code. Using advanced C++ algorithms is certainly possible here, but I think it's overkill.

Comment: Surely we can come up with a totally unreadable templated version with lamba functions and a bind2nd() call ?

Comment: @Martin I was actually thinking of that. Unfortunately my grasp of C++ functional programming is practically non-existent.

Comment: I think calling a web service would be much more fun than lambdas, then the core algorithm isn't just inscrutable, it's stored elsewhere.

Comment: This is no homework question. I am new to c++ and don't have enough knowledge of c++ to program this in a advanced manner. Read: as small as possible. I am able to program this in a simple manner with a for loop and so on, but I was looking for an sophisticated solution, something like the solution of Diego. Next time I will give more information for the reason of the question.

Comment: Also, you'd want to consume contiguous occurrences in case you did not want duplicates. Like for instance, counting how many pieces you'd get after splitting a string by the desired character.

Comment: >  if you're using char*, replace s.size() with strlen(s).

If you do just that with no other code modifications, you'll end up calling `strlen` and scanning the entire string on every loop iteration, making the implementation quadratic. The string length would need to be cached to avoid that.

Answer (score 16):

Using the lambda function to check the character is "_" then the only count will be incremented else not a valid character

```
std::string s = "a_b_c";
size_t count = std::count_if( s.begin(), s.end(), []( char c ){return c =='_';});
std::cout << "The count of numbers: " << count << std::endl;
```

Comment: Please add an explanation - try not to post just plain blocks of code alone.

Comment: What do you think, that your answer offers, what a previous answer hasn't already covered? Please edit and expand your answer.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Used the lambda function to check the character is "_" then only count will be incremented else not a valid character.

Comment: `[]( char c ){if(c =='_') return true; }` invokes undefined behavior because you didn't return a value in all code paths

Comment: as @phuclv suggested, there must be also return false statement `size_t count = std::count_if( s.begin(), s.end(), []( char c ){if(c =='_') return true; else return false; });`

Comment: You don't need the if statement

`size_t count = std::count_if( s.begin(), s.end(), []( char c ){ return c == '_'; });`

Answer (score 15):

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm/count.hpp>

std::string str = "a_b_c";
int cnt = boost::count(str, '_');
```

Answer (score 8):

You name it... Lambda version... :)

```
using namespace boost::lambda;

std::string s = "a_b_c";
std::cout << std::count_if (s.begin(), s.end(), _1 == '_') << std::endl;
```

You need several includes... I leave you that as an exercise...

Comment: Some of the world's top programmers have spent the last 15years evolving C++ to the point where we can write this -  it's not childish!

Comment: Making a point that those who do not know Perl are forced to reinvent it (badly) - now that would be childish!

Comment: Oh, come on, this can also be fun! :) @Roger: Yes, it was kind of an answer to a fun comment by Martin Beckett above. @Martin: Well, yes, it is not particularly appealing, but in the expression you can see clearly _1 is refering to the first parameter to the "lambda", and that it is being compared using "==" to the character... C++0x lambda are not much better in shape, but at least they are standard :)

Comment: @Diego: I like your answer (and wasn't calling it childish, but the comments), though I think you have much too little explanation for it to be a good answer to this question.  I was just trying to show the context to Josh.

Comment: @Diego, I guessed that (in a Perl kind of way) but in c shouldn't the first parameter be _0 ?

Comment: It is ridiculous to leave out the includes.

Comment: why all the complexity when `std::count` already does all what is needed ?

Answer (score 7):

Count character occurrences in a string is easy:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s="Sakib Hossain";
    int cou=count(s.begin(),s.end(),'a');
    cout<<cou;
}
```

Comment: -1 This is the same as the existing top answer from six years earlier – what was this meant to add? There is one difference: this answer uses the wrong header file. stdc++.h is specific to GCC, and even with that compiler it's only intended for use in precompiled headers.

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Answer (score 4):

There are several methods of std::string for searching, but find is probably what you're looking for.  If you mean a C-style string, then the equivalent is strchr.  However, in either case, you can also use a for loop and check each character—the loop is essentially what these two wrap up.

Once you know how to find the next character given a starting position, you continually advance your search (i.e. use a loop), counting as you go.

Answer (score 4):

I would have done it this way :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

int count = 0;
string s("Hello_world");

for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) 
    {
       if (s.at(i) == '_')    
           count++;
    }
cout << endl << count;
cin.ignore();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find out occurrence of '_' in source string by using string functions.
find() function takes 2 arguments , first - string whose occurrences we want to find out and second argument takes starting position.While loop is use to find out occurrence till the end of source string.

example:

```
string str2 = "_";
string strData = "bla_bla_blabla_bla_";

size_t pos = 0,pos2;

while ((pos = strData.find(str2, pos)) < strData.length()) 
{
    printf("\n%d", pos);
    pos += str2.length();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have done something like that :)

```
const char* str = "bla_bla_blabla_bla";
char* p = str;    
unsigned int count = 0;
while (*p != '\0')
    if (*p++ == '_')
        count++;
```

Answer (score 0):

The range based for loop comes in handy

```cpp
int countUnderScores(string str)
{
   int count = 0;

   for (char c: str)
     if (c == '_') count++;
   
   return count;
}
int main()
{
   string str = "bla_bla_blabla_bla";
   int count = countUnderScores(str);
   cout << count << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler in **C++23** (May be some **C++20** compilers also support)

```
    //Inputs : Your string,Search criteria
    int num_items = std::ranges::count("bla_bla_blabla_bla",'_');
    
    //Print output
    std::cout << num_items << std::endl; //3
```

Answer (score -5):

Try

```
#include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;


int WordOccurrenceCount( std::string const & str, std::string const & word )
{
       int count(0);
       std::string::size_type word_pos( 0 );
       while ( word_pos!=std::string::npos )
       {
               word_pos = str.find(word, word_pos );
               if ( word_pos != std::string::npos )
               {
                       ++count;

         // start next search after this word 
                       word_pos += word.length();
               }
       }

       return count;
}


int main()
{

   string sting1="theeee peeeearl is in theeee riveeeer";
   string word1="e";
   cout<<word1<<" occurs "<<WordOccurrenceCount(sting1,word1)<<" times in ["<<sting1 <<"] \n\n";

   return 0;
}
```