# Is there a C++ function to check similarity between strings?

Tags: c++, string, std

is there a c++ standard function to check the similarity between two strings parameters by returning for example the number of similar characters .

Comment: What do you mean by similar?

Comment: what do you mean "number of similar characters"?

Comment: Are you looking for something like Levenshtein Distance (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)? There's no standard function for this, but I'm sure you can find an implementation somewhere.

Comment: You probably are looking for [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance), there are many definitions of edit distances, Levenshtein distance being one of the most common one, but the similarity between all of them is that none of them are available in the standard library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not.  You can view all standard C++ functions at [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com).  There you will see that [the `basic_string` type has nothing like that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [the algorithms library has nothing like that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), and there's pretty much no other place to put something like that, so, no.

Comment: The closest you get is sort twice, then `set_difference`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867890/count-character-occurrences-in-a-string) for each character of the String.

*Extract from the link*

```
#include <algorithm>

std::string s = "a_b_c";
size_t n = std::count(s.begin(), s.end(), '_');
```

There is no function to count similarities like you need.