# Finding number of occurrence of character in sub-string

Tags: c, string

What is the fastest method to find the number of occurrence of character in a sub-string of string?

I have tried the normal scanning each character but the test data is too large.

Comment: `strchr` in a loop while it doesn't return `NULL`

Comment: Give us your code. Is the problem related to the fact that there's too much data to load into memory at once? This is very vague right now.

Comment: If you want to count how many times a particular character appears, then you have no choice but to look at every byte. Otherwise you might be interested by [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) and in general [what grep does](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html)

Comment: Does this have to be C or can you use C++? If so then this answer is properly the most efficient way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867890/count-character-occurrences-in-a-string

Comment: @wybourn why do you ask? I think there would be a c++ tag otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple

```
unsigned int countChar(const char *string, char characterOfInterest)
 {
    unsigned int count; 

    count = 0;
    while ((string = strchr(string, characterOfInterest)) != NULL)
     {
        count  += 1;
        string += 1;
     }
    return count;
 }
```

Comment: This code is calling `strchr` for each character of the string, there is no need to do that.

Comment: Maybe something like `while ((p = strchr(string, characterOfInterest)) != NULL) { count++; string = p + 1; }`  Note: `characterOfInterest == 0` is a special case.

Comment: or maybe `char *p=string; while ((p = strchr(p, characterOfInterest)) != NULL) { count++; p++; }` (to preserve `string` unchanged)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin good suggestion although there is no benefit in that, IMO.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin is there any real difference with this answer, except that **iharob** wrote to `const char *string` as the argument as opposed to its target string?

Comment: @iharob don't be so antagonistic. I was supporting your comment, altering the pointer provided is ok, **DavidC.Rankin** proposed the same thing with another pointer var. Why can't you just forget that I downvoted you once, but have upvoted since many times?

Comment: @WeatherVane I didn't understand your comment at first, and then ... I deleted mine. And I didn't know that you downvoted one of my answers.

Comment: @iharob you once complained about my downvote when I copped to it. If I was out of order, I apologise.

Comment: @WeatherVane - first it is a **comment**, not an **answer**. The reason for it (generally, not with `strchr`) is to preserve the pointer to the original string. So `string` remains `string`. All commenting and answering know, that **it does not matter for this function**, but the poster may not know that failing to do so with other string functions, like `strtok`, or where `string` is dynamically allocated will cause headaches. That's why it was worth a comment.