# array to count number of repietition of each character

Tags: visual-c++

I am a beginner; I want to make an array to count number of repetition of each character on c++.
 for Example: the input array>> [aaa bb cccc] 
              the out put array>>[3 2 4]

Answer (score 0):

There is a great exemple at [Count character occurrences in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867890/count-character-occurrences-in-a-string) , you just need to initialize an array with the characters that you want to count and then launch a for function