# Count how many times a character occurs in an array

Tags: c, arrays, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define N 100

int main()
{

    int count[26] = {0};
    int i;
    char ch ='a';

    printf("Enter a sentence (end by '.'): ");

    while (ch != '.') {
        ch = getchar();

        count[(tolower(ch) - 'a')]++; 

        for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            printf("'%c' has %2d occurrences.\n", i + 'a', count[i]); 
        }
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

The program does what it is supposed to do. The counter works fine the issue is that the program runs though every single letter twice and prints out which letters occurs 0 times. The correct output should be as follows:

Enter a sentence end by '.'

The scanf reads This.

Correct Output:

T occurs 1 times

H occurs 1 times

I occurs 1 times

S occurs 1 times

But the output from the code goes through every single letter and also prints out which letters did not occur at all. I need to get rid of the letters that occur "0 times" and only display letters that occur 1 or more times.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: wrap your `printf` in a conditional, `if (count[i] > 0){ printf(...); }`

Comment: Well yes, you loop over all the letter (indices), and in the loop you unconditionally `printf` the number of appearances of the corresponding letter.  If you want to skip letters with zero appearances then test the number of appearances before you print.

Comment: Found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867890/count-character-occurrences-in-a-string) helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define N 100

int main()

{

int count[26] = {0};
int i;
char ch ='a';

printf("Enter a sentence (end by '.'): ");

while (ch != '.') {
    ch = getchar();

    count[(tolower(ch) - 'a')]++;

    for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        if (count[i] > 0) {
            printf("'%c' has %2d occurrences.\n", i + 'a', count[i]);
        }
    }
}

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just needs a simple `if` to check if the count is more than 0:

```
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    if (count[i] > 0)
    {
        printf("'%c' has %2d occurrences.\n", i + 'a', count[i]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The edit only displays the first letter with amount of occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked great for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define N 100

int main()
{

    int count[26] = {0};
    int i;
    char ch ='a';

    printf("Enter a sentence (end by '.'): ");

    while (ch != '.') {
        ch = getchar();

        count[(tolower(ch) - 'a')]++;

        for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            if (count[i] > 0) {
                printf("'%c' has %2d occurrences.\n", i + 'a', count[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the input into a character array, say `input` with `fgets()` and then loop through the individual characters.

Note that `fgets()` will read in the trailing `\n` (newline) which you may want to remove.

```
char input[100];
fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
```

You may check the return value of `fgets()` to see if it succeeded. It returns `NULL` upon error.

Note that `fgets()` will read in the trailing newline (`\n`) into `input` as well.

You can remove it like

```
input[strlen(input)-1]='\0';
```

Now look at each character in `input`.

```
for(i=0; input[i]!='.' && input[i]!='\0'; ++i)
{
    count[tolower(input[i])-'a']++;
}
```

You can make sure that `input` has a `.` in it with

```
if(strchr(input, '.')!=NULL)
```

[`strchr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html) would return `NULL` if the character is not present in the string.

Finally print the results as you did.

```
for(i=0; i<26; i++)
{
    if(count[i]>0)
    {
        printf("\n%c has %2d.", i+'a', count[i]);
    }
}
```